# Seperating sickness between months in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have set up a table showing number of sick days based on absence start and finish date in Power BI. The date tables have been set up.

I am having an issue with sick days that continue in the following month, for e.g .

Absence Start Date
5 May 21
Absence End Date
5 June 21

My table sums all the absence days in May.

How do I allocate the 25 days in May and then the remaining go to June even though it is one occurrence?

[How Data is being summarised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6PbB.png)

Comment: Edit your question and add a sample data + desired output;

Comment: I've added how the data is being summarised, I need power to pick up in the table in green.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you don't provide enough information about your model/ data. Consider this example. Here is my dummy table:

```
Table 3 = 

var __baseTable =
DATATABLE("StartD",DATETIME, "EndD", DATETIME,
{
    {"2020-01-28","2020-02-24"},
    {"2019-12-23","2020-01-31"},
    {"2020-01-20","2020-02-17"}

} 
)
return
ADDCOLUMNS(GENERATE(__baseTable, CALENDAR([StartD],[EndD])),"Month", FORMAT([Date],"yyyy-mm"), "WorkDay", IF(NOt(WEEKDAY([Date]) in {1,7}) ,1,0))
```

And here are measures (calculating days without a weekend, because I don't have Calendar with businessHoliday):

```
SumOfSickDays = CALCULATE(SUM('Table 3'[WorkDay]))
```

[image]